# OS X Sierra, "Pictures" folder hijacked by an application - how to fix?

Tags: operating-systems, user-folders, file-attributes

A crummy application (MacFamilyTree) somehow hijacked my system's "Pictures" folder.  It thinks it's an application now, and has acquired an 'Open with:' panel in the GetInfo window. There's no way to select "Finder" as the application to open the folder.  Is there a way I can restore its "Folder" identification?  The 'Kind' should show "Folder".  Instead it shows whatever filetype is specified by the assigned application.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been turned into a package by MacFamilyTree. Packages are actually just folders but with special sauce that Finder uses to make them appear as a monolithic item. So, uou can't turn it back into a folder because it is actually already a folder.

Just throw it in the trash, empty trash, and make a new Pictures folder.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to transfer everything to a new folder except the 113 GB of the "Photos Library".  Doesthat need some special treatment?  I have adequate disk space for the transfer.  (Sorry for the dumb question!)

Comment: Photos Library is another "folder disguised as a package" thing. When you say you weren't able to transfer it, what happened exactly? Did you get an error message?

Comment: All solved!   The copying issue was a system time-out problem since the file was so large.  Got that done.  Then I couldn't delete the original "Pictures" folder... a little sleuthing revealed that it's one of the folders the Mac OS protects with an 'ACL entry' to prevent accidental deletion.  I found the terminal commands to execute the delete, and now all is good!  Thanks for your help.